# Using my own API in Alloy

Tags: alloy

Just wondering about how can I use my own API in alloy?

I've developed an API in alloy but i don't know how can I use it?

regards

Moody

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by using "your own API"?

I assume you've developed some modules and predicates in Alloy that you wish to call from the Java API.  In that case, I don't think you can do that directly using the API.  Your best bet is to write Alloy expressions as plain strings in Java, then parse them (e.g., using `CompUtil.parseOneExpression_fromString`), and then evaluate them (e.g., using `A4Solution.eval`, provided that you've already obtain an instance of A4Solution).